# TabBarview com card gerando erro ao carregar dados no flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia, estou começando agora no mundo flutter e estou montando uma TabBarView com card com dados vindos de um banco.
Estou colocando dentro de ListView para poder separar nas tabs e carregando os dados dentro de um ListView.builder. Ao debuggar, vi que os dados estão sendo pegos, porém gera um erro e não carrega na tela.
O erro é:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#0e7dd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'


════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: scrollOffsetCorrection
```

A classe de montagem de tela:

```
class _LacamentosWidgetState extends State<LacamentosWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Lancamentos _lancamentos = Provider.of(context);

    return TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        //aba despesas
        ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Descrição'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        //aba receitas
        ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _lancamentos.itemsCount,
                itemBuilder: (_, int position) {
                  final item = position;
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('sdfd'),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

e a classe de pega os dados:

```
class Lancamento {
  final int id;
  final String descLancamento;
  final DateTime diaLancamento;
  final double valorLancamento;
  final bool isReceita;
  final String tipoLancamento; //FIXO VARIAVEL para enum

  Lancamento({
    this.id,
    this.descLancamento,
    this.diaLancamento,
    this.valorLancamento,
    this.isReceita = true,
    this.tipoLancamento,
  });
}

class Lancamentos with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Lancamento> _items = DUMMY_LANCAMENTOS;

  List<Lancamento> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  int get itemsCount {
    return _items.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um `TabController` a sua classe para trabalhar com a `TabBarView`.

No seu caso seria

```
controller: TabController(length: 2, vsync: this)
```

Uma outra coisa errada é que você esta criando uma lista dentro de outra lista, sem definir o tamanho das listas internas, causando assim um erro ao desenhá-las, pois as `ListView` quando não possuem um *height* especificado, tomam todo o tamanho do Widget pai, e como elas podem ter tamanhos infinitos, nunca terminam de desenhar...

Ao invés de fazer:

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _lancamentos.itemsCount,
        itemBuilder: (_, int position) {
            final item = position;
            return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('sdfd'),
            ),
            );
        }),
    ],
),
```

Faça apenas assim:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _lancamentos.itemsCount,
    itemBuilder: (_, int position) {
        final item = position;
        return Card(
            child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('sdfd'),
        ),
        );
    }
),
```

Obs.: Se precisar ser como está, defina um *height* para as listas internas.

**Classe completa corrigida**

```
class _LacamentosWidgetState extends State<LacamentosWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TabController _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

    return TabBarView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        //aba despesas
        ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Descrição'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        //aba receitas
        ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _lancamentos.itemsCount,
            itemBuilder: (_, int position) {
              final item = position;
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('sdfd'),
                ),
              );
            }
         ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```